# Connecting Synapse/Azure sql db from databricks notebook pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a req where we need to connect to azure synapse from databricks notebook. We had a class for connection which accepts server db username and pwd. We are trying to create obj for this and use the connection but unable to get in where we are getting time out issues. Can you suggest.
Am getting the following error:
('HYT00', '[HYT00] [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have DB enabled in the Azure SQL firewall?

Comment: Also, it's better to use Spark connector instead of ODBC. Databricks has built-in one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/synapse-analytics

Comment: Yes DB enabled in Azure sql firewall, still getting timeout.

Comment: what `nc -vz database_host 1433` gives (port could be slightly different)